# combinatorics and sorting

Tags: combinatorics

There are 5 distinct computer science books, 3 distinct mathe-
matics books, and 2 distinct art books. In how many ways can these
books be arranged on a shelf if no two of the three mathematics books
are together?

Attempt at solution:

First we found the amount of ways to arrange the 7 comp/art books, 7!.
Assuming there is a space between each book for a math book, the first math book has 8 (And 3 books to choose from) ways to be placed. The second has 7 ways(2 books to choose from), and the third has 6 ways.

The answer is 7!*(8*3)*(7*2)*6.

Is this correct? If not, where did we go wrong?

EDIT: This question is not a duplicate because our set of books is distinct where in the other question they are not.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the distinct specification when I closed it.  You have double counted the permutations of the math books.  You should put the math books in order, then you are right that the first has $8$ places, the second $7$ and the third $6$.  You should convince yourself that this gets the possibilities if you change the order of placing the math books once each.

Comment: @Ross: Have a dupe-hammer means that you have a one-vote hammer in reopening duplicates. If you feel that this question should be reopened, you can do it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The non-math books can be arranged in $7!$ ways.

That leaves $8$ "gaps" (including the endgaps) to place the math books. The oldest math book can be placed in $8$ ways, and for each way the second oldest can be placed in $7$ ways, and then the youngest in $6$ ways, for a total of $(7!)(8)(7)(6)$.

Alternately, the **places** to be occupied by math books can be chosen in $\binom{8}{3}$ ways, and then the math books can be permuted among these places in $3!$ ways. Then the non-math books can be permuted in $7!$ ways, for a total of $\binom{8}{3}3!7!$.

**Remark:** The answer proposed in the OP is a hybrid of the two approaches above, and overcounts by a factor of $3!$.